# Static Variable in TSQL?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, variables

I have bunch of servers that I need their information such as servername and instance name and add all these information into a table in Server X. I am using sqlcmd to connect to server X, here is a simple code:

```
declare @servername varchar(30)
set @servername=@@servername
:connect to X
insert into X.table values(@servername)
```

so i thought @servername gets the current servername and then it goes to line 3 and add it to new server(server X), but I was wrong and once it connects to server X it retrieves the data (@servername) from this server. meaning that it can't hold the data. So my question is how to hold the data from old server and not overwrite it, something like Static variable in java.

Comment: It's usually a lot simpler to do these outside the database, for example with a scripting language

Comment: I wish I could, unfortunately I have to use TSQL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SQLCMD happens before processing the script, so you can't use it for your intended purpose.

Have you tried using a linked server and the `EXEC AT` command?

```
EXEC ('INSERT INTO MyTable VALUES (?)', @servername) AT [LinkedServer]
```

http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1757/dynamic-sql-execution-on-remote-sql-server-using-exec-at/

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188332.aspx

Answer (score 0):

If you have the server names before hand, you can use `:setvar myvariable variablevalue` to set a variable that you can access in your sqlcmd script via `$(myvariable)`.

In this situation I would probably do a delimited string of server names to parse.

Take a look at the MSDN https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188714.aspx , for  more examples.